# Beta values for mixed models

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model

First of all, I am very new to statistics, so I apologize if this is a fairly obvious question. I am using R to run mixed models to include in a paper, and my professor has requested the "results" of these models to include beta values and effects. I have used `summary()`but do not see anything called beta values or effects.

Comment: Amazingly, a search for all your keywords--[beta, effect, mix](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=effect+beta+mixed)--turns up almost a hundred posts.  The first few hits look relevant.

Answer (score 5):

Mixed models are so-called because they estimate both random effects and fixed effects.

There is no universal acceptance of what constitutes a random effect and a fixed effect, but a good starting point is to assume that a fixed effect is a variable that remains constant across individuals or experimental units, for example, the "effect" of being male or female, or the "effect" of a treatment in a trial or experiment, whereas a random effect is something that varies across individuals, such as the "effect" of receiving a treatment at a certain hospital, or the "effect" of being a particular individual when repeated measurements are taken.
Note that when a variable is specified as a random effect, it usually also has a fixed effect.

Without any psychic ability to read your professor's mind, I suspect they may be asking to know what the random effects and fixed effects from your model(s) are.  Taking the output from `lmer()` using the built-in `sleepstudy` dataset:

```
> require(lme4)
> m0 <- lmer(Reaction ~ 1 + Days + (1 + Days|Subject), data=sleepstudy)
> summary(m0)
```

which produces:

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: Reaction ~ 1 + Days + (1 + Days | Subject)
   Data: sleepstudy

REML criterion at convergence: 1743.6

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.9536 -0.4634  0.0231  0.4634  5.1793 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr
 Subject  (Intercept) 612.09   24.740       
          Days         35.07    5.922   0.07
 Residual             654.94   25.592       
Number of obs: 180, groups:  Subject, 18

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)  251.405      6.825   36.84
Days          10.467      1.546    6.77

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
     (Intr)
Days -0.138
```

This shows the random effects and fixed effects estimates and (for the fixed effects their standard errors and t values). Other packages such as `nlme` will produce equivalent output.
 Here we have a random intercept for `Subject` because observations are clustered (repeated) within subjects, so each subject has it's own intercept; and a random coefficient for `Days` so that each subject has its own slope for the variable `Days`.

As for "beta values", these are usually the estimates of the fixed effects, in the above example, we have 2 fixed effects, the intercept (often called "beta-0" or $\beta_0$, estimated here as 251.405) and the fixed effect of `Days` (often called "beta-1" or $\beta_1$ because it is the first fixed effect after the intercept, here estimated as 10.467).

Comment: I would think "beta" denotes the standardized regression coefficient, no?

Comment: @rolando2 why "standardized" ? Maybe I have missed your point ?

Comment: I'm used to seeing "b" as indicating an unstandardized regression coefficient, and "beta" or Greek equivalent as standardized.  Calling "summary()" tends to produce the former, whereas I think the OP is asking about the latter.

Comment: @rolando2 could be, I suppose, though I think it usage isn't standardized (excuse the pun !) and may differ considerably between different applied fields - I've seen both *beta* and $\beta$ used for both.

Comment: @RobertLong What does it mean having a negative correlation in the Fixed Effect that you have on the bottom ($Days -0.138$)?

Comment: Also, in the Random effect you have $Days      Variance   35.07 Std.Dev.  5.922   Corr 0.07$ What does it mean that Corr 0.07 ? What would it mean if it is negative ? Sorr for the questions, just trying to understand these models too hehe